# nginx $scheme variable behind load balancer

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb

Is it possible to force nginx *$scheme* value to "https" if nxinx is running behind load balancer?

In my scenario Load balancer takes care of https communication with client and forwards requests to nginx as raw http. I know I can do something like this to detect https

```
set $my_scheme "http";
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "https") {
    set $my_scheme "https";
}
```

but I'm just curious if there is something like `real_ip_header` function for IPs.

Are there also some headers I need to update when detecting https manualy?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Our setup is the same as yours, only using `map` instead of `if/set` (as recommended by the [nginx devs](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,11794,84008#msg-84008)).

```
# Sets a $real_scheme variable whose value is the scheme passed by the load
# balancer in X-Forwarded-Proto (if any), defaulting to $scheme.
# Similar to how the HttpRealIp module treats X-Forwarded-For.
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $real_scheme {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
```

P.S. I agree, a `real_scheme` module would be nice!